# RDP Clipboard File transfer in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, copy, clipboard

I don't like the "new" Feature in Windows 2008 R2. We had some Terminal servers used by a lot of users.

If the User enables the Clipboard function in their Remote Desktop Connection, the user can copy a file from the RDP connection to their local computer and the other way around.

I am looking for a way to allow copy/paste of text and pictures between the RDP connection and the local machine, but not files.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't exactly a "new" feature in 2008 R2 - it's been around since at least 2003

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no file transfer only text and pictures... I feel sorry for the misunderstanding must have on my bad English are.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for myself. It's possible to change the .exe file that is responsible for the copy & paste between the RDP connection and the local computer. Take the `rdpclip.exe` from a older version of Windows (such as Windows Server 2003), copy it, and paste it into the new Windows 2008 R2 `C:\Windows\System32\`

Before you do it, you have to be the owner of the original .exe file, otherwise it's not possible to remove the original file.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could enable drive mapping on the RDP client, then the terminal server could see the client's C:\ drive (and/or other drives), and you could move files around that way...

Answer (score 0):

you can actually copy files between remote desktops, but it requires allowing "mounting of remote disks" during connection time. It's off by default.